# Get process ID of Phantomjs through python

Tags: python, phantomjs

I have been running python script to run phatomjs command this way:

**cmd="phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=yes rasterize.js input output"**

**status, output = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)**

The status and output are fine.

I would like to get the PID of the phantomJS process.
Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subporcess module here:

```
import subprocess
cmd="phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=yes rasterize.js input output"
proc = subprocess.Popen([cmd])
print "PID of running process::", proc.pid
```